# Cannot import npm modules after converting ES5 require to ES6 import

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import

I am trying to convert my npm package imports from ES5 (require) to ES6 (import...from) but I keep getting unexpected identifier errors. What should I be looking out for?

I have read through forums but honestly not sure what to try. I checked the documentation in MDN but none of those worked. Every single package has been tried individually but none of them work.

```
// changed version
import fs from 'fs';

// old imports
// const fs = require('fs')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because they're NPM modules - IIRC you *have* to use `require` for those.

I *think* you can change the command you use slightly and it *should* work if your Node version is high enough. You'll also need to change the file type from `.js` to `.mjs` (module JS):

```
node --experimental-modules moduleApp.mjs
```